# How to bold everything before a colon on each line in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document that looks like this:

> randomword: definition
>   anotherrandomword: definition
>   yetanotherrandomword: definition
>   multiple word term: definition

and I want to make it look like this:

> **randomword**: definition
>   **anotherrandomword**: definition
>   **yetanotherrandomword**: definition
>   **multiple word term**: definition

I cant do this manually because I have hundreds of lines, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has a caveat, in that it needs a return character at the beginning of the file in order to match the beginning of the line.  Also, it bolds the colon.

Search replace, and enable "Use wildcards"

In the search box, enter

```
^13(*:)
```

This searches for a return character, followed by a sequence of characters ending in a colon.

In the replace box, enter

```
^p\1
```

Then click Formatting / Font / Bold

The ^p replaces the return character with a return character, and the \1 matches what was found in the brackets in the search pattern.  So basically it replaces what it found in the search, but adds bold formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: If they're all in a row, hold the `alt` key and start at the top, drag your cursor down and select all of the words. Then, hit `cntrl+b`, or just click 'Bold'... This should work, unless some words are a lot longer than others, in which case parts of other words will be bolded as well.

Comment: @User802303 Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

this works better

1. First, open search and replace box in Microsoft Word. You might click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> buttons and then
2. In the search box, enter: `(^013[!:]*:)` .
3. Enable "Use wildcards" after clicking More >> button.
4. In the replace box, enter: `\1`.
5. Then, choose Formatting/Font/Bold after clicking More >> button.
6. Lastly, click Replace All button.